# How the express the position of a particle using the spherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coordinate-systems, spherical-harmonics

I have a bit of a weird question, the spherical harmonics are defined as following for $m\ge0$:

$$ 
Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi) = (-1)^m \sqrt{ \frac{(2l+1)(l-m)!}{4\pi (l+m)!} } P_{l,m}(\cos(\theta)) e^{im\phi}
$$

Does anyone know if there's any operators able to "extract" the angles from this expression. For $\phi$, it should be something like this:

$$
\hat{\Phi} Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi) = \left ( -i\frac{\partial}{\partial m} - \pi \right) Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi) = \phi Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)
$$

But for $\theta$, it's a bit more tricky and I don't know how to extract it from the Legendre polynomials. Any help would be appreciated. The Legendre polynomials are generated by the following expression:

$$ P_{l,m}(\cos(\theta)) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l \, l!} \sin^m(\theta) \frac{d^{l+m} \sin^{2l} (\theta) }{d\, \cos^{l+m} (\theta) } $$

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the coefficient of the leading power of $x$ in $P_{l,m}(x)$... a question for math.SE.

Comment: Your operator $\hat\Phi$ has two problems: 1. It takes the partial derivative with respect to the *discrete* variable $m$. This one *may* be able to fix that by adding a subset $S\subset\mathbb R^2$ for $(l,m)$ to the domain of $Y$. However, 2. I severely doubt that $Y$ is an eigenvector of $\hat\Phi$ to the eigenvalue $\phi$: after all, $m$ appears in the square root as well as in $P_{l,{\bf m}}$ but this seems to not be reflected in $\hat\Phi$ as you wrote it. So even for the "simpler" variable $\phi$ in the current form I see little chance to extract it via some differential operator